# How to utilize/resolve a promise from a Dynamic Import

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dynamic-import

How do you utilize / resolve the `promise` from a `Dynamic Import`?

The idea below is to import the `jspdf` library only if it's needed.

```
to_pdf() {
      const filename = `${this.staff.staff_no}.pdf`

      html2canvas(document.getElementById('rpt'), { scale: 4 }).then(c => {
        import('jspdf').then(jsPDF => { // error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: jsPDF is not a constructor
          let pdf = new jsPDF({
            orientation: 'p',
            unit: 'mm',
            format: 'a4',
            putOnlyUsedFonts: true,
            compress: true,
            precision: 4
          })
          const hgt = (c.height / c.width) * 200
          pdf.addImage(c.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1), 'JPEG', 4, 10, 200, hgt)
          pdf.save(filename)
        })
      })
    }
```

Code above gives this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: jsPDF is not a constructor
```

Comment: There are many resources online. https://v8.dev/features/dynamic-import. `import()` resolves to the module (an object). The exports are it's properties.

Comment: @Wendelin Ah, I see. but i am not able to call `new` from the returned module. like i could have if i had used the regular static import

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `import()` resolves to the module (an object). The exports are it's properties. (as Wendelin commented)

You need to know how things inside the module are exported. In this case:

```js
import('jspdf').then(module => { 
  let jsPDF = module.default
  let pdf = new jsPDF({
    orientation: 'p',
    unit: 'mm',
    format: 'a4',
    putOnlyUsedFonts: true,
    compress: true,
    precision: 4
  })
});
```

**UPDATE**: For some reason `module.jsPDF` didn't worked in all environments. Fixed by using `module.default` (to access default export)....

Comment: your example works ... no clue what i'm doing wrong. could it be vue?

Comment: i jusrt added my exact code: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-g9qb9
it works in sand box but fails on my laptop // i'm at a loss

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203513/discussion-between-charles-okwuagwu-and-michal-levy).